# jetty 6 index.html welcome page not working

Tags: servlets, jetty, web.xml

I think Im going insane, but I cannot get a simple default index.html page to display in jetty.

the root context defined in the web.xml is

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and I have welcome file as:

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But upon entering http://localhost:8182/api/ i get a 404. This works FINE in tomcat so what am I missing??????????? Am doing something dumb I know but still...works on tomcat.

thanks

Comment: Jetty have many mechanismo for deploy a WebApplication: WAR, exploded archive, from you Java Code. Which is you deployment mode?

Comment: mvn jetty:run embedded from maven. I think i', being silly, is it even possible to have a default index.html page if you only have the root context as defined above? Dont I need an actual application name after the '/*'? So for example /rest/* which would be appended to the context root /api?

Comment: ignore m.y previous comment im just going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough information in your question to be 100% sure, but I suspect you're running into problem that "welcome files need to actually exist".

This page provides more details, including how to overcome the problem:
http://web.archive.org/web/20150520205320/https://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Welcome+files+not+working

The short explanation is that, by default, this version of Jetty will not treat a servlet as matching a *welcome-file* unless an actual file also exists.

The reason for this, is that JSPs are implemented as a servlet, and if Jetty matched welcome files just because there was a servlet-mapping match, then `index.jsp` would *always* match as a welcome file, but you only want that to happen if there really is an `index.jsp` file.